# $or requires nonempty array exception

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to get data from Mongodb Database, My code as follow,

```
    $collection = $global["dbmongo"] -> person_uuid;
    $rows = $collection->find(array("p_uuid" => $global['uuid'],
            '$or'=>array(

                    'expiry_date'=>null,
                    'expiry_date'=> '0000-01-01 00:00:00'
            )
    )
    );
```

But it shows,

> $or requires nonempty array

if i write `echo "count".$count;
        var_dump($rows);`

Then the output is `countArrayobject(MongoCursor)#48 (0) { }`, addition to above output
Please help me.

Comment: array !== associative array / map

Comment: $or is an array of arrays, with each element of the parent array being a clause

Comment: @Prinzhorn It does in PHP

Comment: Thanks, So how can i fix that ? In test case, I finding with 'expiry_date'=> '0000-01-01 00:00:00'

Comment: wrap each line of the $or clause with `array(` so it is an set of array clauses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this part:

```
array(
  'expiry_date'=>null,
  'expiry_date'=> '0000-01-01 00:00:00'
)
```

The keys are the same and because of this one overwrites another. You can use [$in](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator and do something like

```
'expiry_date' => array(
  '$in' => array(null, '0000-01-01 00:00:00')
)
```

Also it is hard to understand what exactly are you looking for here.